# Problem with Node JS and promises return before finish

Tags: node.js, promise, youtube-api

I try to get the last video list uploaded of a specific channel ID of Youtube with statistics. I get the list but not statistics.

I think the result is returning before Object assign. How can I return the result after Object assign ?

This my code :

```
async function (inputs, exits) {

    var { google } = require('googleapis');
    var youtubeApiKey = 'API_KEY';
    var service = google.youtube('v3');

    // Get upload ID to list uploaded videos
    service.channels.list({
        part: 'contentDetails',
        id: inputs.ytbIdChannel,
        key: youtubeApiKey,
    })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads) {
                let uploadsId = res.data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

                // With the uploadID, get all uploaded videos
                service.playlistItems.list({
                    part: 'snippet',
                    playlistId: uploadsId,
                    maxResults: '12',
                    key: youtubeApiKey,
                })
                    .then(res => {
                        this.youtbeVideos = res.data.items,

                        // For each videos in list, inject the statistics object and return all videos
                        this.youtbeVideos.forEach(video => {
                            let videoId = video.snippet.resourceId.videoId

                            service.videos.list({
                                part: 'statistics',
                                id: videoId,
                                key: youtubeApiKey,
                            })
                                .then(res => {
                                    Object.assign(video, res.data.items[0].statistics)
                                    return exits.success(
                                        this.youtbeVideos
                                    );
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.error(error);
                                });
                        });



                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code and verified it is working with the YouTube API.

First, make an asynchronous function by replacing:

```
service.channels.list({
    part: 'contentDetails',
    id: inputs.ytbIdChannel,
    key: youtubeApiKey,
})
    .then(res => {
```

with:

```
service.channels.list({
    part: 'contentDetails',
    id: inputs.ytbIdChannel,
    key: youtubeApiKey,
})
    .then(async res => {
```

Then, in order to correct you need to replace the contents of the `if (res.data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads)` block with this code instead:

```
let uploadsId = channels.data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

// With the uploadID, get all uploaded videos
let videos = await service.playlistItems.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    playlistId: uploadsId,
    maxResults: '12',
    key: youtubeApiKey,
})
this.youtbeVideos = videos.data.items;

// For each videos in list, inject the statistics object and return all videos
for (let video of this.youtbeVideos) {
    let videoId = video.snippet.resourceId.videoId

    let stats = await service.videos.list({
        part: 'statistics',
        id: videoId,
        key: youtubeApiKey,
    })
    Object.assign(video, stats.data.items[0].statistics)
}

return exits.success(
    this.youtbeVideos
);
```

The two key changes I have made are:

1. Using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) so that the iteration over `this.youtbeVideos` pauses for the statistics to be retrieved before moving on
2. Moving the return and call to `exits.success` outside of the loop so that it will return the data once after all statistics have been added

You can [run my working copy](https://repl.it/repls/FragrantAcidicProjector) online here - just add your API key for YouTube.

When the list returns it will contain all the statistics as expected.

Comment: Your welcome :) I'm happy everything is working for you now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change .then for async/await.

For example:

```
service.getAll()
  .then(res => {
      service.getById(res.id)
        .then(res =>{
           .....
       })
    })
```

You can use await:

```
const res1 = await service.getAll();
const res2 = await service.getById(res1.id);
```

It's more clean code, and with await, node stop all steps and await it. When finish, will go to next step... and then again.. await, execute, await, execute.

Answer (score 0):

probably you you should return or 'await' the promises. Not just call them.
Otherwise nobody knows when the function is ready.

write `await` before every `service.XXX.list`, make your callback functions `async` and use `for loop` or `promise.all` instead of `forEach` for `this.videos` because otherwise you cant wait for every promise ([await within forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/2519073))

And maybe this is to fix:

- you call `return exits.success(this.youtbeVideos);` for *each* video, shouldn't it be for all videos done?
- `Object.assign(video, res.data.items[0].statistics)` probably assigns every time same keys (overwrites)

**disclaimer:** i don't know the api/your call environment, so this is only suggestions, that maybe will be useful.